# Many2one field in a Custom Setting page in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, erp

I am trying to add many2one field in a setting page in odoo11. I am able to add char or integer field in a setting page but with Many2one field I get an error.

The Error :

```
     psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer:"double.accounts(406,)"
     LINE 1: ...FROM "double_accounts" WHERE "double_accounts".id IN ('double.acco...
```

here is my code :

class AccountSetting(models.TransientModel):

```
_inherit = 'res.config.settings'

authtoken_module = fields.Char(default_model='account.move')
organization_module = fields.Char(default_model='account.move')
double_accounts_id = fields.Many2one('double.accounts', string="double Entery", default_model='account.move')

def get_values(self):
    res = super(AccountSetting, self).get_values() 
    res.update({
       'authtoken_module': self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('account.authtoken_module', default=''),
       'organization_module': self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('account.organization_module'),
 #### the error that i am facing from this line 
       'double_accounts_id': self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('account.double_accounts_id', default=''),
 ####
   })
    return res

def set_values(self):
   super(AccountSetting, self).set_values()
   self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('account.authtoken_module', (self.authtoken_module or ''))
   self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('account.organization_module', (self.organization_module or ''))
   self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('account.double_accounts_id', (self.double_accounts_id or ''))
```

Comment: I think this what you need to do set the value to id not the record set it self. `self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('account.double_accounts_id', (self.double_accounts_id.id or ''))`     -->  self.double_accounts_id.id

Comment: I got odoo server error    (Database fetch misses ids (('395',)) and has extra ids ((395,)), may be caused by a type incoherence in a previous request )

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked very well into it. But it seems you get a recordset out of your parameter instead of an ID. So a simple solution is to put a `.id` to the end of the marked line. But that isn't the full solution, cause your default has to be changed to `self.sudo().env['account.double_accounts_id']`, where `.id` will work, too.

I'm really wondering why you get a recordset, maybe someone can answer that.

Comment: your solution does not work... I am still getting record set with no value  psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "double.accounts()"

Comment: Did you change the `default` of `get_param`?

Answer (score 0):

Searching I found this thread, so I'm writing in case it helps others. For v14.

```
class ResConfigSettings(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = "res.config.settings"
    my_field = fields.Many2one("RELATED_MODEL", string="RELATED FIELD", store=True)

    @api.model
    def get_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).get_values()
        value = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('MODULE_NAME.my_field')
        res.update(my_field=int(value))
        return res

    @api.model
    def set_values(self):
        res = super(ResConfigSettings, self).set_values()
        self.env['ir.config_parameter'].set_param('MODULE_NAME.my_field',self.my_field.id)
        return res
```

To check if value is stored, can access to "Settings/Technical/System parameters".